# Add Gesture to UICollectionViewCell subview with xib

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xib, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to add a gesture to a subview of a `UICollectionViewCell` make with xib, I'm doing this:

**.h**

```
@interface MyCell : UICollectionViewCell <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> 

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerButton;

@end
```

**.m**

```
@implementation MyCell

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initialize
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
    [panGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];

    if (self.containerButton) {
        NSLog(@"ok"); //not enter here
        [self.containerButton addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
    }
}

-(void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    if (self.containerButton) {
        NSLog(@"ok 2");
    }
}
```

I have created the UICollectionViewCell subclass connected with the xib file, where I have created the container button view, if I try to add the gesture in the initialize method, the containerButton is nil, so doesn't work, but in the `prepareForReuse` method is not empty, I can add the gesture there? or I can do it in other place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
    [panGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];

    if (self.containerButton) {
        NSLog(@"ok"); //not enter here
        [self.containerButton addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
    }
}
```